# looping through json data from url using php

Tags: php, json

Hi I am attempting to echo out data returned from an api I'm working with utilizing the following code:

```
<?php

ini_set("include_path", '/home/matthewt/php:' . ini_get("include_path") );
// This sample uses the Apache HTTP client from HTTP Components 
(http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)
require_once 'HTTP/Request2.php';

$url = $request->getUrl();

$headers = array(
    // Request headers
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' => 'my_id',
);

$request->setHeader($headers);

$parameters = array(
    // Request parameters
);

$url->setQueryVariables($parameters);

$request->setMethod(HTTP_Request2::METHOD_GET);

// Request body
$request->setBody("{body}");

try
{
    $response = $request->send();
    echo $response->getBody();
}
catch (HttpException $ex)
{
    echo $ex;
}
```

Everything up until this point works great and returns json data that basically looks like this: (I shortened the amount of fields to save space)

[{"GameID":49810,"Season":2017},{"GameID":49811,"Season":2017}]

What I need to know is how to loop through this data to print out the results for each game. I know I have to use something like this:

```
$arr = json_decode();

foreach($arr as $item) { //foreach element in $arr
    $game_id = $item['GameID']; //etc
}
```

But I'm not sure what needs to be decoded...is it $response ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$response->getBody()` contains your json, then json_decode it, then this will be your array of objects which you can loop over.

So try this:

```
// snip
try
{
    $response = $request->send();
    $arr = json_decode($response->getBody());

    foreach((array) $arr as $item) { //foreach element in $arr
        echo $item->GameID; //etc
        echo $item->Season; //etc
    }
}
catch (HttpException $ex)
{
    echo $ex;
}
```

Comment: np, happy coding.